# LogCat not working after update to Android N

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, logcat

I recently updated my Nexus 5x to `Android N preview`, I updated the SDK plugin for Android N on Eclipse too.

But *Eclipse still does not recognize the API of my own*, and thus the `LogCat is not working when debugging the app`.

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YhV6.png)

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXG1F.png)

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Use Android Studio. Eclipse is no longer supported for Android development.

Comment: did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: See fix here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42451046/3147100

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to [Android: ADT doesn't recognize the format of Nougat logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39302436/android-adt-doesnt-recognize-the-format-of-nougat-logcat)

I just tried using the solution provided by https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware and it worked: Using command line, type "adb logcat".