# Android: ADT doesn't recognize the format of Nougat logcat

Tags: android, adt, logcat, android-logcat, android-7.0-nougat

I have an "old" ADT:

```
Eclipse IDE for Android Developers  23.0.2.1259578  adtproduct
```

connected to a Nougat Pixel C.

ADT doesn't succeed to read properly the format of logcat as shown on this screenshot:

[image]

There was no problem before the upgrade to Nougat, aka with Marshmallow. Is there anything to do (except abandoning ADT...)?

Comment: Yep. ADB changed. ADT didn't.

Comment: I don't want to abandon ADT...

Comment: Use `adb logcat` in a terminal window.

Comment: Check this response for the fix: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41486502/3147100

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Issue**:
-Eclipse is no longer supported by Android
-Android Nougat/7 this broke (new LogCat protocol I read)

**Eclipse fix** (custom build)
Credit goes to: Romano in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41486502/3147100
-Download: https://github.com/khaledev/ADT/releases  ADT-24.2.0-20160729.zip
-Eclipse menu Help->Install New Software... -> Add -> Archive... 
-Select the downloaded zip -> Ok -> Check box next to "Developer Tools" -> Next
-Proceed with install defaults

**Quick Alternative Fixes:**
-"adb logcat"   (\SDK\platform-tools\ADB.exe) (easy, but console style)
-\SDK\tools\monitor.bat (Android Device Monitor) (easiest option)
-\SDK\tools\DDMS.bat (Dalvik Debug Monitor) (deprecated but still works)