# Android Nougat device showing unknown target in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, ddms, android-7.0-nougat

I have a Android Pixel C that has an android version 7.1.1.

I'm using MAC OS X, I have followed all the instructions, i.e. allow usb debugging/ non market apks etc, however the device is showing up "**unknown target**" in eclipse. See Screenshot below.

[image]

Here is some key point which need to be notice.

- I'm able to install .apk file from terminal.

[image]

- I'm able to transfer data from MAC to device and vice versa.
- I checked USB info in system information.

[image]

- Android Studio is recognizing the target and device is perfectly working with the same.

[image]

Restarting adb with this shell command and rebooting phone and MAC did not worked for me.

**How can I get Eclipse to recognize the target ? Does anyone know how to fix this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this link will help you

Custom ADT (Eclipse ADB)

https://github.com/khaledev/ADT/releases

or

if do you want only show logcat

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39632018/4359490

Answer (score 0):

install your usb driver manually . Device manager> click on usb > Select action and >add legacy hardware > in select your driver zip file and install it.

Comment: why there is need for install USB driver?

Android Studio is recognizing the target and device is perfectly working with the same.

Comment: if target is unknown then its means your driver not working perfectly sometimes.  So, try this may be it will help you

Comment: Installed USB driver PL2303_MacOSX_1.6.1_20160309 does not work for me :(
http://plugable.com/2011/07/12/installing-a-usb-serial-adapter-on-mac-os-x/